# How to email Faculty Search Committee for seminar without implying to hurry on my application?

Tags: email, interview, seminars, faculty-application

I had recently applied to several prestigious institutes in India. Just to explain the recruitment process in these institutes a Faculty Search Committee goes through your application that comprises of CV, teaching statement, research statement, list of publications, etc. Based on your academic credentials they invite you for faculty interview/seminar.

If the candidates are abroad you could inform the Faculty Search Committee you are in India for vacation and usually they invite you for an interview/seminar before finalizing the application.

Now, I will be going to vacation and I need to email the Faculty Search Committee that I would be available during a certain period. I need to compose the email such that I do not imply in speeding up the application. This is what I had in mind:

> Dear Faculty Search Committee,
>
> I had applied for a faculty position in the Department of XYZ on
>   D1-M1-YY. Please do not consider this email to speed up my application,
>   but for your information I will be in India from D2-M2-YY to D3-M3-YY.
>   During this period I would be happy to give a seminar at ABC.
>
> Looking forward to hear from you.
>
> Regards,
>
> PQR

Please let me know if this email would affect negatively and how can I improve the same for a better email communication.

Comment: Why are you writing this email? Why do they need "this information" if you don't want them to interview you while you are already in India?

Comment: The way I read it, PQR does want to be interviewed while they are in India, but does not want to make a negative impression by trying to accelerate the committee's process.

Comment: @xLeitix In most cases the candidate is abroad doing a postdoc or PhD. There are proviisons to conduct the seminar bypassing some steps. That is to stay if there are couple of steps involved prior to your faculty seminar in a normal case. In special circumstances you can give the seminar before those steps are complete.

Comment: @cag51 Adding to my previous comment. The candidates usually conduct the seminar via Skype, but if you happen to be in India at any time during the application process  you can inform them that you are in India and would be happy to give a seminar. But should my email convey that I am not hastening the application process. I somehow want the email to imply this, any better ways of doing this?